# Need some help making background glow fog

Tags: modeling, texturing, eevee-render-engine

I need some help with making the background glow that appears in the painting.

[image: painting]

I tried doing it with photoshop and a bit of image magic (https://i.stack.imgur.com/RpDWw.jpg) but I didn't get to the wanted solution. I want it to look as close as possible to the painting (this also means in shape and form).

[image: rendered image]

Thanks in advance!
phantom

Comment: if you are in Eevee, activate the Bloom option, increase the Emission strength

Comment: Please don't use external links to images. You can insert an image directly into your question either from the link or by dragging and dropping it directly into the question field.

Comment: @JohnEason I tried doing it but it said it was too heavy for some reason

Comment: @phantomderp The image you've linked to is almost 4 Meg in size so I'm not surprised!

Answer (score 0):

[image]

In the first step, I would improve the lighting. There are 3 suns in the painting that emit light. If the light source is behind an object, a so-called rim light is created. This is the glow around the silhouette of the planets.

I've made a quick "overpaint" of your render which is used as a background image. Just forgot to reset the camera rotation so it looks a bit messy:

[image: scene setup]

The two main suns are simple spheres that have an emissive material (strength 3, yellow emission color). Because the emission material alone is too weak to illuminate the whole scene there are area lights behind each sun to illuminate the back of the planets.

There are also a few spotlights to illuminate the front of the planets because if you have only a light source in the background then the planets will appear black to the camera.

The nebulae can be created with transparent alpha planes, which also have an emission material (strength 1, and light blue emission color). Search for "free fog overlay" or "cloud overlay" to find some. These are the smaller planes in the screenshot above.

[image: compositor]

In the compositor, the glow for the suns and the rim light is created with the help of two *Glare* nodes. Also, the color is adjusted a bit.

For the planets, play with the *Roughness* and *Specular* values and thus influence the glow. For example, with a *Fresnel* node you can make only the outermost edge of the planet smooth and reflective, while the inner is rougher and reflects less light. In the example, it's done for the main planet.